# Issue of trigger for datetime column

Tags: sql-server-2008, datetime

I am using an `Insert` trigger on a table where I copy one record from one table to another.

Everything is ok. It works fine except on `datetime` columns. When I add a `datetime` column into the inserted values, then I get an error:

> Invalid column name

My code is

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Insert_MoinitoringBasic]
ON [dbo].[M0_BasicInfo]
FOR INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    MERGE [MonitoringROSCII].[dbo].[MonitorBasicInfo] AS d
    USING (SELECT DistrictID, upazilaID, LC_ID, AcademicYear, Trimester, RepID,
                  CASE VisitType 
                    WHEN 'Initial validation' THEN 1
                    WHEN 'Full validation' THEN 2
                    WHEN 'Compliance monitoring' THEN 3
                 END AS VisitTp
           FROM INSERTED) AS s ON s.DistrictID = d.DistrictID 
                               AND s.upazilaID = d.upazilaID 
                               AND s.LC_ID = d.LCID 
                               AND s.AcademicYear = d.LCVisitYr 
                               AND s.Trimester = d.Trimister 
                               AND s.RepID = d.MOID 
                               AND s.VisitTp = d.VisitType
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
       UPDATE 
       SET DistrictID = S.DistrictID

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
       INSERT (DistrictID, UpazilaID, LCID, VisitType, LCVisitYr, Trimister, MOID,  
 LCStatus, IfCloseWhy, OthersSpecify,LC1stVstDt)
       VALUES (DistrictID, UpazilaID, Lc_ID, VisitTp, AcademicYear, Trimester, RepId, 
               2, 'No', 'No', FirstVisitDate);
END
```

Here the last line `FirstVisitDate` which is a `datetime` column. Without this column, it worked nice but when I include this column, it shows the error mentioned above.

Can anybody help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error text suggests, you are refering to a column that does not exist.

In the SELECT part of your MERGE statement, there is no output column named FirstVisitDate, which is why you're getting the error...